# Map Reduce that counts a parameter from a line and then count a second parameter

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

Imagine I have a logfile full of lines:

"a,b,c", whereas these are variables that can have any value, but re-occurances of the values do happen and that is what this analysis will be about.

#### First Step

Map all **'c'** URLs, where **'a'** equals a specific domain, e.g. "stackoverflow.com" and c equals URLs like "stackoverflow.com/test/user/" I have a regex written that accomplishes this.

#### Second Step

Count (reduce) all counted **c**'s (URLs) so then I have a list with total counts for each URL. This works fine.

**Third Step**

(not implemented yet and topic of this qeustion)

Look for all **b**'s (browser names) for each counted URL from step 2. Give back a relational list, e.g. a dictionary ADT or JSON, that looks as follows:

```
[
   {
    "url":Stackoverflow.com/login, 
    "count": 200.654, 
    "browsers":[
      Firefox 33, 
      IE 7, 
      Opera
    ]
   },
   {..},
   {..}
 ],
```

I was thinking of introducing a combiner in my code (see below), or chain stuff. But the real question here is how can my job flow be optimsed so that I have to run through all log lines only once?

#### MapReduce Job (mrjob)

```
FULL_URL_WHERE_DOMAIN_EQUALS = mySuperCoolRegex

class MRReferralAnalysis(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):

        for group in FULL_URL_WHERE_DOMAIN_EQUALS.findall(line):
            yield (group, 1)

    def reducer(self, itemOfInterest, counts):
        yield (sum(counts), itemOfInterest)

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep( mapper=self.mapper,
                    reducer=self.reducer)
        ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRReferralAnalysis.run()
```

#### Wrap up

This is what I want in pseudo code:

```
LOGS_1 -> MAPREDUCE OVER SOME_CRITERIA -> LIST_1

FOR EVERY ITEM IN LIST_1:
    LOGS_1 -> MAPREDUCE OVER ITEM_CRITERIA -> LIST_2
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the log file, just a few lines, and the regex for the **first step**?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **non-MRJob, non-mapreduce** solution.  It runs through the log-file once.  It varies a bit from your output spec, `browsers` is list of (browser, count) tuples and it produces dictionaries which are unordered. `collections.OrderedDict` could be substituted.

Assumes a file that looks like this

```
domain,browser,url
wonderful.edu,IE,wonderful.edu/pix
odd.org,Firefox,odd.org/login
wonderful.edu,Opera,wonderful.edu/pix
```

Read the file and sort by domain, url, browser  for use with `itertools.groupby`

```
import collections, itertools, operator
with open('fake.log') as f:
    lines = [tuple(line.strip().split(',')) for line in f]

lines.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0,2,1))
```

A few useful callables

```
domain = operator.itemgetter(0)
browser = operator.itemgetter(1)
url = operator.itemgetter(2)
```

Use `collections.Counter` to count the browsers for each *unique* url.  The url count is the sum of all the browser counts.

```
results = list()
FULL_URL_WHERE_DOMAIN_EQUALS = re.compile('.*\.(edu|org|com)')
for d, group in itertools.groupby(lines, domain):
    # this outer loop only needed if filtering by domain
    if not FULL_URL_WHERE_DOMAIN_EQUALS.match(d):
        print d
        continue    
    for u, group2 in itertools.groupby(group, url):
        browsers = itertools.imap(browser, group2)
        browser_count = collections.Counter(browsers)
        results.append({'url' : u,
                        'count' : sum(browser_count.viewvalues()),
                        'browsers' : browser_count.items()}
                       )
```

Produces

```
[{'browsers': [('Chrome', 2), ('IE', 4), ('Opera', 7), ('Firefox', 6)],
  'count': 19,
  'url': 'odd.org/foo'},
  {...},
  {...}]
```

Comment: Interesting line of thought, i will give it a serious look on Monday. Thanks.

Comment: Ok problem with your code, it is not a(ny) map reduce job, maybe I should have better emphasised that I have gigabytes of data to process. I post my solution as soon as I have fiddled it out.

Comment: Use this and set it to run overnight while your fiddling- see how far it gets.  Still need to persist it somehow.

Comment: Hi, this will take 7 days to run at least. I need map reduce. Thanks anyway. I think I figured a way to achieve it.